# Shared eigenbasis of commuting Operators

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, commutator, eigenvalue

Suppose I have two Hamiltonian pieces $H_1$ and $H_2$ such that $[H_1,H_2]=0$. Then we know that the two pieces have shared eigenbasis. Assume both $H_1$ and $H_2$ have eigenvalues 2 and -2. Let $|\psi\rangle$ be an eigenstate of $H_1$, then I think if $|\psi\rangle$ is not an eigenstate of $H_2$ then we can conclude that both 2 and -2 are degenerate (thanks for correcting), since $|\psi\rangle$ and $H_2|\psi\rangle$ have the same eigenvalue. However, I'm still a bit confused about how can I find the shared eigenbasis between the two Hamiltonians? Do I need to consider the superposition (linear combination) of the degenerate states? Thanks!!

Comment: The eigenvalue does is not necessarily degenerate, e.g. if $|\psi\rangle$ is also an eigenvector of $H_2$.

Comment: @NDewolf Oh that's right. Thanks!

Comment: Re "I think we can conclude...", try $H_1=H_2=\pmatrix{2&0\cr 0&-2\cr}$.

Comment: @WillO Thanks for the correction:)

Comment: I don't understand your question: take H1= diag(2,2,-2)  and H2=diag(-2,2,2).   All linear combinations of the first two eigenvectors will be   eigenvectors of H1, but not H2, with *one* exception. What is it you want to do with them? Resolve them?

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Yes that's what I want. Assume 2 and -2 both have degeneracy of 2 in the two hamiltonians. I'm not pretty sure how to apply $H_2$ to the (superposition) eigenvector of $H_1$. What is that exception? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you are after, but from the comment I understand that you assume something like
$$ H_1=\operatorname{diag} (2,2,-2,-2), \qquad H_2=\operatorname{diag} (2,-2,2,-2),
$$
in a space parameterized by eigenvectors $\psi_{1,2,3,4}$,
that is, $H_1|\psi_1\rangle = H_2|\psi_1\rangle = 2|\psi_1\rangle$;  $H_1|\psi_2\rangle = -H_2|\psi_2\rangle = 2|\psi_2\rangle$;  $-H_1|\psi_3\rangle = H_2|\psi_3\rangle = 2|\psi_3\rangle$;  $H_1|\psi_4\rangle = H_2|\psi_4\rangle = -2|\psi_4\rangle$.

In general, all vectors $\alpha |\psi_1\rangle + \beta  |\psi_2\rangle $ are eigenvectors of $H_1$ with eigenvalue 2, but *not* of $H_2$, since it acts markedly differently on them,
$$
H_2 (\alpha |\psi_1\rangle + \beta  |\psi_2\rangle)=2(\alpha |\psi_1\rangle - \beta  |\psi_2\rangle), 
$$
with one (two) exceptions.
The exceptions are for either *α* or *β* vanishing, in which case you have excluded the freak circumstance of unshared eigenvectors.

Likewise for the $\gamma |\psi_3\rangle + \delta  |\psi_4\rangle $
subspace.

So, you parameterize the eigenvectors of $H_1$ corresponding to eigenvalues 2 and -2, respectively, and then run through each set finding the special two representatives which are also, exceptionally, eigenvectors of $H_2$ as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Should the superposition at the right-hand-side be $2(|1⟩+|2⟩)$ ?

Comment: No, not in general: You posited it not be an eigenvector of $H_2$. It collapses to an eigenvector only when α or  β vanish.

Comment: Thanks!! So the equation $H_2(|1⟩+|2⟩)=2(|1⟩−|2⟩)$ is not a Schrodinger equation unless either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ equal to 0, right? I'm still a little bit confused about how it comes from.

Comment: Right. The vector acted upon is not an eigenfunction. It comes about by definition/assumption: $(H_2  -2)\psi_1=0=(H_2  -2)\psi_3=(H_2  +2)\psi_2=(H_2  +2)\psi_4$, of course!

Comment: If I let $\alpha=0$, then $H_2\beta|\psi_2\rangle=2(-\beta)|\psi_2\rangle$. Can I conclude that $\beta|\psi_2\rangle$ is a shared eigenvector of $H_1$ and $H_2$, but for $H_1$ its eigenvalue is 2, while for $H_2$ its eigenvalue is -2?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer to stress that is what was assumed. For the basis given, simultaneous diagonalization, all four eigenvectors are shared. Conversely, rotations in degenerate subspaces spoil that.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's really helpful:)